# More Like This 2:?

Tags: word-property, cryptic-clues

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #12: mobile-friendly puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/monthly-topic-challenge-12-mobile-friendly-puzzles).</sub>

---

This is the second part of the series "More Like This", named after the section in the Oxford Learner's Dictionary. Unfortunately, the first part was deleted.

It is for gathering the peculiar clues from various sites.
New clues are scheduled to appear in the spoiler at the end of this post.

Can you find anything in common in these clues?

These clues are divided into two groups. The solution words in Group 1 share a property that is not seen in the other group.

**Group 1**

1. The Arabic metal
2. Metal company
3. A tool to help examine the inner structure of secret construction
4. It is a way to tell people apart
5. Fashionable home
6. The first person in team regularly returns
7. Light metal for a short duration
8. Round height of interjection of excitement
9. Return of a total victory - very healthy
10. French metal, alternatively

**Group 2**

1. Adolf Hitler's exclamation of pain
2. Type of radio for linking after first person
3. First article, not second article
4. Perform first note
5. Board game head
6. That person's tag
7. Refusal of poisonous gas
8. Belonging to old French pioneer
9. Heavy metal operating system
10. The people I'm with are west and east

---

Try to solve the clues.

Answer (score 7):

These clues can be answered as follows:

**Group 1:**

> 1. The Arabic metal **AL** = [The [in] Arabic (AL)] & [metal (Al, Aluminium)]
>  2. Metal company **CO** = [Metal (CO, Cobalt)] & [company (CO.)]
>  3. A tool to help examine the inner structure of secret construction **CT** = [A tool to help examine the inner structure ([CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CT_scan))] & [(-constru)CT(-ion)]
>  4. It is a way to tell people apart **ID** = [It (ID, in Latin)] & [a way to tell people apart (ID, as in 'identification')] *(thanks @caPNCApn in comments)*
>  5. Fashionable home **IN** = [Fashionable (IN)] & [home (IN)]
>  6. The first person in team regularly returns **ME** = [The first person (ME)] & [(-t)E(-a)M<]
>  7. Light metal for a short duration **MO** = [Light metal (Mo, Molybdenum)] & [a short duration (MO)]
>  8. Round height of interjection of excitement **OH** = [round (O) + height (H)] & [interjection of excitement, (OH)]
>  9. Return of a total victory - very healthy **OK** = [Return of a total victory (KO<)] & [very healthy (OK)]
>  10. French metal, alternatively **OR** = [French metal (OR is ‘gold’ in French)] & [alternatively (OR)]

**Group 2:**

> 1. Adolf Hitler's exclamation of pain **AH** = [Adolf Hitler (AH)] & [exclamation of pain, (AH)]
>  2. Type of radio for linking after first person **AM** = [Type of radio (AM)] & [for linking after first person ([I]… AM)
>  3. First article, not second article **AN** = [First article (A) + not (N)] & [Second article (AN)]
>  4. Perform first note **DO** = [Perform (DO)] & [first note (DO, in Solfege)]
>  5. Board game head **GO** = [[Board game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)) (GO)] & [head (GO, as in ‘leave’)]
>  6. That person's tag **IT** = [That person (IT)] & [tag (IT, the playground game)] (I can also see an argument for this one being HE, as some games of tag use the word ‘He’ to represent the player who has to catch the others…)
>  7. Refusal of poisonous gas **NO** = [Refusal (NO)] & [poisonous gas (NO, [Nitrogen Monoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_oxide))
>  8. Belonging to old French pioneer **OF** = [Belonging to (OF)] & [old (O) + F(-rench)]
>  9. Heavy metal operating system **OS** = [Heavy metal (Os, Osmium)] & [operating system (OS)]
>  10. The people I'm with are west and east **WE** = [The people I’m with (WE)] & [W (west) + E (east)]

What do those in the first group have in common that those in the second do not? They are all...

> ...**abbreviations for US states**!
>
>  AL = Alabama, CO = Colorado, CT = Connecticut, ID = Idaho, IN = Indiana, ME = Maine, MO = Missouri, OH = Ohio, OK = Oklahoma, OR = Oregon.
>
>  None of those in Group 2 are.

Also worth noting:

> The prominent use of '2' in the title and talk of this being the 'second' puzzle in a (fictional) series are both pointers that we are looking exclusively for 2-letter words!

Comment: I wonder if #4 in group 1 is the first rot13(&yvg qqrs gung V'ir frra: jvgu "VQ" zrnavat "vqragvsvpngvba" naq "vq", nf va "vq, rtb, naq fhcre-rtb")

Comment: @samm82 I contemplated that, but I didn't enough about psychology to be confident there :) I thought that that part of the psyche was more to do with impulses than identity, necessarily. I also tried to make "I had" or "I would" fit there but can't quite shoehorn it in...

Comment: just as a side note: as a German speaker, A.H. probably would have said "Au!" = "Ouch!" for expressing pain, not necessarily "ah!", which in German is more an expression of astonishment (well, could also be used for pain). But this doesn't change anything in the final result.

Comment: samm82 is on the right track rot13(vq zrnaf vg va yngva)

Comment: @caPNCApn That's a lot more satisfying! I was trying to Google ("vq if vg") which didn't really give me anything  - so this is just a straight (qqrs), but still a clever one

Comment: @caPNCApn Ah, that works a bit better, thanks :)

Comment: Moly is denser than iron. "Light metal"?

Comment: @DrXorile Indeed, I have the same quibble myself. I think the OP is basing this off it having a 'relatively low' atomic number in comparison to the higher numbered metals...!

Comment: I think it was likely an oversight. I mean, I get that heavy and light are relative (eg the light rare earths are Nd and Pr). But light metals unqualified are things like Al and Be. Ti maybe also. But denser than Fe is not light...